# Why doesn't Cloudant / CouchDB compress HTML from the show function?

Tags: couchdb, gzip, cloudant

I have a database in Cloudant, and a show function in my design document which generates hefty HTML files:

```
function(){
  return {
    body : doc.bunchOfHTML,
    headers : {
      "Content-Type" : "text/html"
    }
  }
}
```

And I've noticed that accessing this page will give back uncompressed HTML. At the same time, when I access my CSS files as attachments of the document, I notice that they *are* compressed.

Why isn't the output of the show function compressed, and how can we make it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably an overlooked / not yet implemented feature.

However, if your documents do not depend on query parameters and are static documents, you could store the HTML as an attachment and use routing to access them. Refer to [Cloudant's blog post on the _rewrites array](https://cloudant.com/blog/pretty-urls-with-cloudant/) for more information (tip: pay special attention to the 'relative paths' section at the end):

```
[{
    "from": "/mydocs/:docid",
    "to": "/../../:docid/show.html",
    "query": {} 
}]
```

Drawback to this method is that your 404s will be ugly, unless you have so little documents that you can route them individually.